# CASE inside a FROM clause 

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case

Is it possible to use CASE inside a FROM clause in a t-sql query?
For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM CASE
    WHEN column_ = 'firstColumn'
        THEN table_ t, firstTable fT
    ELSE table_ t, secondTable sT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your input. I actually ended doing something similar to Quassnoi suggestion:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_ t, firstTable fT

UNION

SELECT *
FROM table_ t, secondTable sT
```

I don't know what I was thinking. I should have figured that out earlier.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable t
CROSS APPLY
        (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    firstTable ft
        WHERE   t.column = 'firstColumn'
                AND ft.id = t.joincolumn
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  *
        FROM    secondTable st
        WHERE   (t.column <> 'firstColumn' OR t.column IS NULL)
                AND st.id = t.joincolumn
        ) q
```

Comment: I stand corrected. :-) +1, but I'm glad I don't work with you if you do stuff like this. ;-)

Comment: @KenWhite: what's bad in working with a person aware of `CROSS APPLY`? :)

Comment: Nothing wrong with knowing it, as long as you know how to use it *very* judiciously. :-)

Comment: While this answer can work (if the UNION ALL works because the columns in the two tables are compatible), the execution plan might be horrible and the database design is potentially flawed (you've got a multi-foreign key) - so just because you can work around the bad database design using this technique does not eliminate the fact that the database design should be questioned.

Comment: @CadeRoux: this can be rewritten as a `UNION ALL` but in this case a double scan over `mytable` is required. It's not a problem if the index on `column` is used to access `mytable` or something other than a nested loops is used for the join, but the `CROSS APPLY` solution would offer a single scan on `mytable`.